# Quick question about the row sums of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I have a theorem in my text book which isn't proven or explained (its left till a later more advanced course I'm assuming)

Basically we have a matrix where the elements in each column add to 1, and when it is squared, or raised to any power, the elements in each column still add to one.

My questions are:

1. Does this property always hold?
2. Does it hold if the it is the row elements that sum to 1?
3. Is there a name for this property?
   and if you can be bothered,
4. Is there a simple way to prove it? keeping in mind that in the course im doing, we've only done matrix manipulations, and have just started determinants, so anything involving the trace or eigenvectors/values, while surely more elegant might be above my level.)

I realise this might be a lot to ask, but anything you have to offer is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking. Are you asking if we assume the elements in each column of a matrix $A$ add up to $1$, then is it true for powers of $A$ and is it true for the rows?

Comment: as in, if the elements in each row of A sum to 1,  do the elements in each row of $A^{n}$ still sum to 1

Comment: This is a Markov Matrix, if I am not wrong, or a double stochastic matrix.

Comment: hey @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг, yes the question is about a markov matrix, do you know if there is a specific theorem for the property I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you two hints, each can solve your problem independently:

Hint1: let ${\bf P}$ be your transition matrix, then ${\bf P}^n$ gives you the probability of transition from one state to another with $n$ repetitions of an experiment.

Hint2: if ${\bf P}$ and ${\bf Q}$ are doubly stochastic, then ${\bf PQ}$ is doubly stochastic too.